# C: questions about function prototype in header file

Tags: c

1. Normally we declare a function prototype in header file like:

   `void function();`

   Can this function take any argument?
2. If the function takes integer as argument, we write: 
   `void function(int);`

   But sometimes I see people write: `void function(int*);`

   What is the `*` doing here?
3. If the function can a single argument of several types, like integer or
   double, what should we do?

Comment: 1: No, 2: read about what's a **pointer**. 3: EDIT: do you mean "function that takes *both* integer and double (`void function(int, double)`) or function that could take *either*? In the second case, look up on **function overloading**. Pretty useful

Comment: @Fureeish function that could take either. I thought 1. means can take any kind type and any number of arguments before.

Comment: @Fureeish is pointer somewhat similar to array? I see that people write `int*` in prototype but in the main file the function is taking an integer array.

Comment: Is some way, you *could* say that, but the real answer is **no**. Pointer of a type T (int, double, char...) is a special variable that holds a memory adress to a variable of a type T, allocated on a heap, rather than a stack. So why does is sometimes behave like an array? Well, suppose you allocate memory for 15 integers, then you create a pointer to the first one. Since they are stored one after the other, you can access them using *pointer arithmetics*. It's a broad topic, I suggest you getting a good book or following a good tutorial on the language

Comment: @Fureeish thanks. now I understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Normally we declare a function prototype in header file like:
   >
   > ```
   > void function();
   > ```
   >
   > Can this function take any argument?

   It is unspecified what arguments this function will take.
2. > If the function takes integer as argument, we write:
   >
   > void function(int);
   >
   > But sometimes I see people write: void function(int*);
   >
   > What is the `*` doing here?

   This is a [pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) to an `int`.
3. > If the function can take several types of argument, like integer and double, what should we do?

   `int` and `double` are incompatible types. You can't take one function that takes either one, or the other. You can't define two different functions with two different types, but that share the same name, either.

Comment: for 1.: It is unspecified what arguments this function will take. Is this the case where we do not know which type it will take, or it just cannot take any argument?

Comment: @kyle We do not what kind of argument it will take. To declare that `function` shouldn't take any arguments, you need to use the `void` keyword: `void function(void);`

Comment: For 3, overloaded functions are not allowed in C.

Comment: @Alexander I have a follow-up question: But why don't we just specify every function prototype as 1., why do we need to specify the type then?

Comment: @kyle By that reasoning, why have types at all? Why not just work with bits and bytes?

Comment: I suspect that for (3) it might be `void function(int x, double y);` that would be relevant — though the question does use 'or' in which case things are more confused.  A single C program cannot reliably contain both `void function(int);` and `void function(double);`, at any rate (unless there is `static` to alter the behaviour).

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Good catch.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  but isnt it the purpose of header file, that can be used in different main file? If the function can take only a single argument that can be of the type of `double` or `int` only, should I just use 1. instead? But in the first comment in my question, the answer is no. In 1., the function cannot take any argument. Which is correct?

Comment: @Kyle I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: When it comes to defining the function, if it takes one argument, it can only take an argument of one type.  (I suppose you could try using a `union` type, but you'd need to know the correct type, which entails a discriminated union, usually achieved with a structure which contains a union and a discriminator — a member that identifies the type currently held in the union.)  What you declare in the header should match what you define.  You cannot define both `void function(int)` and `void function(double)` — only one of those can actually be a part of your C program.

Answer (score 1):

1. The question itself is worded incorrectly. This is not a prototype at all. This is a *non-prototype* function declaration.

   It does not say anything about function arguments, which is exactly what makes it different from prototype. The function declared in this way can be called with any set of arguments.

   However, if the arguments used in the call (after usual arithmetic conversions) do not match the parameters used the actual definition (in number and type), the behavior is undefined. If the actual function is defined as variadic (has `...` in the parameter list), the behavior is undefined.
2. These are prototypes. The first one says that the function has a single `int` parameter. The second one says that it has a single `int *` parameter (a pointer to `int`). There's nothing special about it if you know what pointers are.
3. It is not clear what is being asked. "What should we do?" I don't know... Fly to Hawaii and spend five days dancing naked in the rain.

   This function is declared as taking several arguments of different types

   ```
   void foo(int, double, char, short *);
   ```

   There's nothing special about it. If you meant something else - clarify the question.